# (Excel) Using defined range (from address functions) in min/max functions

Tags: excel

I have located the desired beginning and end of a range through a series of address functions. When I try to call the results of those address functions into the min/max function, it is taking in the actual cell address that contain the address functions, and not the listed addresses from the address functions.

This was my solution: =MIN(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(D3,'BLX Historical'!A:A,0),5,1,1,"BLX Historical")):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(E3,'BLX Historical'!A:A,0),5,1,1,"BLX Historical")))

Comment: Have tried using cell(“contents”,(cell with address formula) but it still throws a #value error.. really at a loss here as doing this manually is not scalable

Comment: If you are passing a cell address as a string to a function that expects a range, that will never work.  Show us your code (all formulas, and sample data) and we can help you fix it - edit it into your Q

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Use of the indirect function is what I needed.

Comment: Pretty sure you can make this non-volatile if you would share your formula, input and desired output. Otherwise good job on figuring it out yourself.